# Centrar imagen de carousel bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estoy haciendo una galería de fotos con un carousel de bootstrap 4 pero la imagen se me ve al lado izquierda de este así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado darle un margin-left pero la imagen no me queda responsive así que lo he quitado, acá dejo el código html

```html
    <h3 class="card-title text-center" style="margin-top: 10px;">AGUAS OCULTAS</h3>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"
            aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1"
            aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2"
            aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="3"
            aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="4"
            aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="5"
            aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="6"
            aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="7"
            aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="8"
            aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="9"
            aria-label="Slide 3"></button>

        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="img/aguas10.jpg" alt="" id="aguas10" onclick="imagen('aguas10')" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/aguastodas.png" alt="Análisis territorial.
                Unión de diferencias" id="aguas2" onclick="imagen('aguas2')">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/aguaspa.png" alt="Parte alta. Presencia de
                Niebla." id="aguas3" onclick="imagen('aguas3')">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/aguascc.png" alt="Cuatro Corredores.
                Quebradas." id="aguas4" onclick="imagen('aguas4')">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/aguasze.png" alt="Zona de Encuentro.
                Transición" id="aguas5" onclick="imagen('aguas5')">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="img/aguasda.png" alt="Domesticación del Agua. Agua al
                mar" id="aguas6" onclick="imagen('aguas6')">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item ">
            <img src="img/agua7.jpg" alt="Análisis territorial. Estrategias
                por estrato" id="aguas7" onclick="imagen('aguas7')">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item ">
            <img src="img/agua8.jpg" alt="Fotomontaje" id="aguas8" onclick="imagen('aguas8')">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item ">
            <img src="img/agua9.jpg" alt="Fotomontaje" id="aguas9" onclick="imagen('aguas9')">
          </div>
        </div>

        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
          data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Atrás</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
          data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Siguiente</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Puedes inspeccionar el elemento de la imagen, para verificar la propiedad `display` de la imagen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay una class en bootstrap 4 (desconozco si en las versiones anteriores existe) que sirve para centrar las imágenes.

```
<img src="..." class="rounded mx-auto d-block" alt="...">
```